# Why I keep getting 401 from my webrequest code in C#

Tags: c#

If I use a regular url it works fine and if I use google domains update url I get 401 error. This is my first try on C# application.

```
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://UUUUUUUUUUUUU:PPPPPPPPPPPPP@domains.google.com/nic/update?hostname=subdomain.example.com") as HttpWebRequest;

        //request.Accept = "application/xrds+xml";  
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.102 Safari/537.36 Viv/1.97.1246.7";
        request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        request.PreAuthenticate = true;
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        WebHeaderCollection header = response.Headers;

        var encoding = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII;
        using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), encoding))
        {
            string responseText = reader.ReadToEnd();
            //responseddns = responseText;
            MessageBox.Show(responseText);
        }
```

If I use http://example.com/getip.php it works fine I can see the output.

Comment: 401 is for unauthorized access. Make sure you are accessing publicly available url.

Comment: Also make sure your url exists and you can access it in browser.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot use

```
> `CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;`
```

since the url is the domain.google.com's domain. 
You need to enter your google credentials or else directly use
http://example.com/getip.php as u did before

Comment: I am using credentials properly, I only removed the username and password just to post here. If I use the url directly inside the browser it works fine and If I use the exact url in c# I get error 401.